# My long polling is taking time to return the result

Tags: php, jquery

As the title states most of the question I have implemented long polling on a real time web chat, the problem is that I'm receiving the feedback from the server very late.... I compared it to a script made with the exactly same long polling.

Here's my code:
https://batutachat.000webhostapp.com/

```
username: admin
password: admin
```

Refresh when you see alert saying 1.

My long polling function js :

```
pollServer = function(lastLog) {
    var last = $("#chat_logs_container li").last().attr("id");
    if(isTrue) 
    {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "system/get_logs.php",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: {last: last},
                success: function(e) {
                    var lastLog = e.last_id;
                    var messageLog = e.main_logs;
                    renderMessage(lastLog, messageLog);
                    
                }, dataType : 'json', complete: pollServer(lastLog), timeout: 2000,
            })
        },1000);
    }
}
```

My Render message :

```
renderMessage = function(lastLog, messageLog) {
    var last = $("#chat_logs_container li").last().attr("id");
    if(last < lastLog) {
        $("#chat_logs_container").append(messageLog);
    }
}
```

My Get Logs .php :

```
<?php
    require("config.php");
    $last = $_POST['last'];
    $clogs = '';
    $last_log = '';
    $log = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM batuta_chat WHERE chat_id > '$last' ORDER BY chat_id ASC");
    if($log->num_rows > 0) {
        while($chat = $log->fetch_assoc()) {
            $last_log = $chat['chat_id'];
            $clogs .= createLog($chat);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode( array(
        "main_logs" => $clogs,
        "last_id" => $last_log,
    ), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

His Long Poll Function Js

```
chat_reload = function() {
    var cPosted = Date.now();
    var postTime = Date.now() + speed;
    var checkType = $('#main_chat_type').attr('value');
    var priv = $('#get_private').attr('value');
    logsControl();
    $.ajax({
        url: "system/chat_log.php",
        type: "post",
        cache: !1,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            fload: fload,
            caction: cAction,
            taction: tAction,
            last: lastPost,
            snum: snum,
            preload: privReload,
            priv: priv,
            lastp: lastPriv,
            pcount: pCount,
            room: user_room,
            token: utk
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.check == 99 || response.check == 888) {
                location.reload();
                return !1
            } else {
                var answerTime = Date.now();
                var mLogs = response.main_logs;
                var mLast = response.main_last;
                var sesCompare = response.ses_compare;
                var getDel = response.del;
                var checkRank = response.urank;
                var action = response.action;
                var cact = response.cact;
                var pLogs = response.priv_logs;
                var pLast = response.priv_last;
                var getPcount = response.pcount;
                var iconPrivate = response.icon_private;
                var curp = response.curp;
                var newTopic = response.topic;
                var newTaction = response.taction;
                var friendsCount = response.friends;
                var newsCount = response.news;
                var adminshipCount = response.adminship;
                var radioClubCount = response.radioClub;
                var complaints = response.complaints;
                var noticeCount = response.notify;
                var reportCount = response.report;
                var setroom = response.setroom;
                var useData = response.use;
                var rm = response.rm;
                var tname = response.tname;
                var room_effects = response.room_effects;
                balStart = response.acval;
                speed = response.speed;
                uSound = response.user_sound;
                inOut = response.acd;
                if (room_effects != 0) {
                    if (room_effects == 1) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Fireworks/Fireworks.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Fireworks/Fireworks.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 2) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Stars/Stars.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Stars/Stars.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 9) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Rain/Rain.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Rain/Rain.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 10) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Football/Football.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Football/Football.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 11) {
                        var effects_check = "css/cricket/cricket.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/cricket/cricket.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 12) {
                        var effects_check = "css/15AUG/15AUG.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/15AUG/15AUG.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 6) {
                        var effects_check = "css/KashmirDay/KashmirDay.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/KashmirDay/KashmirDay.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 7) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Rose/Rose.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Rose/Rose.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 8) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Propose/Propose.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Propose/Propose.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 4) {
                        var effects_check = "css/14AUG/14AUG.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/14AUG/14AUG.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 5) {
                        var effects_check = "css/EID/EID.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/EID/EID.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                    if (room_effects == 3) {
                        var effects_check = "css/Lights/Lights.css" + bbfv;
                        if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                            $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/Lights/Lights.css" + bbfv)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (tname == 'system') {
                        tname = 'Lite'
                    }
                    if (tname == null) {
                        tname = 'Lite'
                    }
                    var effects_check = "css/themes/" + tname + "/" + tname + ".css" + bbfv;
                    if (effects_check != $("#actual_theme").attr("href")) {
                        $("#actual_theme").attr("href", "css/themes/" + tname + "/" + tname + ".css" + bbfv)
                    }
                }
                if (checkRank != user_rank || action != userAction) {
                    location.reload()
                } else if (sesCompare != sesid) {
                    overWrite()
                } else if (mLogs == 99 || lastPost == mLast) {
                    scrollIt(fload);
                    if (answerTime < postTime) {
                        fload = 1
                    }
                } else if (mLogs.indexOf("b_o_o_m") >= 1) {
                    $("#show_chat ul").html(mLogs);
                    cAction = cact;
                    lastPost = mLast;
                    fload = 1
                } else {
                    if (answerTime < postTime) {
                        $("#show_chat ul").append(mLogs);
                        if (mLogs.indexOf("my_notice") >= 1 && fload == 1 && uSound > 1) {
                            usernamePlay()
                        }
                        if (fload == 1 && uSound > 1) {
                            messagePlay()
                        }
                        if (focused == !1) {
                            PageTitleNotification.Off();
                            PageTitleNotification.On(system.newMessage)
                        }
                        cAction = cact;
                        lastPost = mLast;
                        scrollIt(fload);
                        fload = 1
                    }
                }
                beautyLogs();
                for (var i = 0; i < getDel.length; i++) {
                    $("#log" + getDel[i]).remove()
                }
                if (answerTime < postTime && curp == $('#get_private').attr('value')) {
                    if (privReload == 1) {
                        if (pLogs == 99) {
                            $('#private_content ul').html('')
                        } else {
                            $('#private_content ul').html(pLogs)
                        }
                        scrollPriv(privReload);
                        lastPriv = pLast;
                        privReload = 0;
                        morePriv = 1
                    } else {
                        if (pLogs == 99 || lastPriv == pLast) {
                            scrollPriv(privReload)
                        } else {
                            if (curp == priv) {
                                $("#private_content ul").append(pLogs)
                            }
                            scrollPriv(privReload)
                        }
                        if (getPcount !== pCount && uSound > 0) {
                            privatePlay();
                            pCount = getPcount;
                            if (focused == !1) {
                                PageTitleNotification.Off();
                                PageTitleNotification.On(system.newMessage)
                            }
                        } else {
                            pCount = getPcount
                        }
                        lastPriv = pLast
                    }
                }
                if (answerTime < postTime && newTopic != '' && newTopic != actualTopic) {
                    $("#show_chat ul").append(newTopic);
                    actualTopic = newTopic;
                    scrollIt(fload);
                    tAction = newTaction
                }
                if (iconPrivate != 0) {
                    $("#notify_private").text(iconPrivate);
                    $('#notify_private').show()
                } else {
                    $('#notify_private').hide()
                }
                if (answerTime < postTime && useData == 1) {
                    if (newsCount > 0) {
                        $('#news_notify').text(newsCount).show();
                        if (!$('#chat_left:visible').length) {
                            $('#bottom_news_notify').text(newsCount).show()
                        }
                        if (notifyLoad > 0) {
                            if (newsCount > curNews) {
                                newsPlay()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#news_notify').hide();
                        $('#bottom_news_notify').hide()
                    }
                    if (adminshipCount > 0) {
                        $('#adminship_notify').text(adminshipCount).show();
                        $('#notify_admiship').text(adminshipCount).show();
                        if (notifyLoad > 0) {
                            if (adminshipCount > curAdminship) {}
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#adminship_notify').hide();
                        $('#notify_admiship').hide()
                    }
                    try {
                        if (complaints > 0) {
                            var x = document.getElementById('compliants');
                            x.style.color = 'red'
                        } else {
                            var x = document.getElementById('compliants');
                            x.style.color = 'white'
                        }
                    } catch (err) {}
                    if (radioClubCount > 0) {
                        $('#radioClub_notify').text(radioClubCount).show();
                        $('#notify_radioClub').text(radioClubCount).show();
                        if (notifyLoad > 0) {
                            if (radioClubCount > curRadioClub) {}
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#radioClub_notify').hide();
                        $('#notify_radioClub').hide()
                    }
                    if (reportCount > 0) {
                        $('#report_notify').text(reportCount).show()
                    } else {
                        $('#report_notify').hide()
                    }
                    if (friendsCount > 0) {
                        $("#notify_friends").text(friendsCount).show()
                    } else {
                        $("#notify_friends").hide()
                    }
                    if (noticeCount > 0) {
                        $("#notify_notify").text(noticeCount).show()
                    } else {
                        $("#notify_notify").hide()
                    }
                    if (notifyLoad > 0) {
                        if (noticeCount > curNotify || friendsCount > curFriends) {
                            notifyPlay()
                        }
                    }
                    grantRoom(setroom);
                    curNotify = noticeCount;
                    curFriends = friendsCount;
                    curNews = newsCount;
                    curAdminship = adminshipCount;
                    notifyLoad = 1
                }
                if (rm == 1) {
                    roomBlock()
                } else if (rm == 2) {
                    fullBlock()
                } else {
                    unblockAll()
                }
                inactiveControl(cPosted)
            }
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: There is a code injection hazard. Avoid using unchecked variables inside queries. How long does that query take? How many rows in the table? Do you have an index on `chat_id`? Which part exactly takes a long time? Did you try to profile it or measure time of different parts of the script?

Comment: @AterLux I'll surely keep the hazards in mind, thanks for that :)... The script works exactly smooth in my localhost. The part where new results have to be fetched takes time..

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem or a jQuery problem?